# Confusing errors using predict to map between matrices

Tags: warning-messages, machine-learning

I'm messing around with the new features involving machine learning in Mathematica 11, and one easy thing to try is to make a machine learn the matrix exponential function. The first silly idea I had way to try making a table of random matrices, computing their matrix exponentials, and feeding that into `Predict`. In more detail:

```
matin = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]], {count, 1, 3000}, {j, 1, 
10}, {k, 1, 10}];
matout = Table[MatrixExp[matin[[count]]], {count, 1, Length[matin]}];
Predict[matin -> matout]
```

This returns the following error:

```
Predict::mlincfttp: Incompatible variable type (Numerical) and variable 
value ({{-0.94519-2.18056 I,<<8>>,-0.570606-0.108024 I},<<9>>}).
```

I've messed around with variations on this (wrapping the matrices in `Dataset[]`, etc., trying one by one) and each case generates this error that I haven't seen posted elsewhere. Any guidance on where this is coming from?

Comment: Seems the issue might be that some of the resulting matrices have complex components...

Comment: That occurred to me so I made the matrices explicitly real in another piece of code and the same error appeared.

Comment: Perhaps `Predict` doesn't actually support multidimensional output... My apologies, not caffeinated enough to help today! Hopefully someone else will chime in.

Comment: @CarlLange That appears to be the case. `Predict[RandomReal[1, 3] -> RandomReal[1, 3]]` works, `Predict[RandomReal[1, {3, 3}] -> RandomReal[1, 3]]` works, `Predict[RandomReal[1, {3, 3}] -> RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]]` fails.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I see, what a shame. Do you happen to be aware of a straightforward generalization for multidimensional outputs? I suppose it doesn't really matter since there should be more clever ways to fit the matrix exponential function. Thanks for the help!